# Why does this prediction function need a zero when using cumsum()?

Tags: r, function, prediction

I'm taking a udemy course, and in one lesson there's a function that takes a vector x of 1's and 0's and based on the previous sequence of k values predicts the next value. I'm trying to wrap my brain around why I need to include a 0 in the below function in the line `csx <- c(0,cumsum(x)).`

```
 predc <- function(x,k) {
  n <- length(x)
  k2 <- k/2
  # the vector pred will contain our predicted values
  pred <- vector(length=n-k)
  csx <- c(0,cumsum(x))
  for (i in 1:(n-k)) {
    if (csx[i+k] - csx[i] >= k2) 
        pred[i] <- 1 
     else 
        pred[i] <- 0
  }
  return(mean(abs(pred-x[(k+1):n])))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0` is there to handle the case `i=1` correctly. With the prepending `0` the first element of your vector of cumulative sums `csx` will consequently also be `0`, i.e. `csx[1]=0`. This means that for `i=1` we will evaluate the statement

```
if (csx[1+k] >= k2) pred[1] <- 1 else pred[1] <- 0
```

This `i=1` is usually seen placed outside (prior to) the `for` loop in prediction functions such as this one, in case we could not make use of a `cumsum()`. I.e., without having `cumsum`, we'd evaluate the `i=1` expression prior to the loop with a form like

```
mysum <- sum(x[1:k]
if (mysum >= k2) pred[1] <- 1 else pred[1] <- 0
```

and thereafter repeatedly update `mysum` in the for function ranging from `i=2` to `n-k`. Finally note that `sum(x[1:k]` is equivalent to element `k+1` in the `c(0,cumsum(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

It is there to handle the first element's lag correctly. You can try the following piece of code to see the difference vividly:

```
predc <- function(x,k) {
  n <- length(x)
  k2 <- k/2
  # the vector red will contain our predicted values
  pred <- vector(length=n-k)
  csx <- c(0,cumsum(x))
  for (i in 1:(n-k)) {
    if (csx[i+k] - csx[i] >= k2) pred[i] <- 1 else pred[i] <- 0
  }
  return(mean(abs(pred-x[(k+1):n])))
}

x <- sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE)
pred(x, 1)
[1] 0.4974975
```

Modify the function without prepending 0:

```
predc <- function(x,k) {
  n <- length(x)
  k2 <- k/2
  # the vector red will contain our predicted values
  pred <- vector(length=n-k)
  csx <- cumsum(x)
  for (i in 1:(n-k)) {
    if (csx[i+k] - csx[i] >= k2) pred[i] <- 1 else pred[i] <- 0
  }
  return(mean(abs(pred-x[(k+1):n])))
}

pred(x, 1)
[1] 0
```

Note: same convergence problem happens for pred(x, 2) without that first prepended lag term.

Comment: Just a note: It's not there to handle _"the case pred(x, 1)"_ (as in the _specific call to_ `predc`, note the missing `c` typo in your functions calls above), it's needed for all calls to `predc` for the prediction function to work as intended (unshifted). The prepending 0 is specifically used in the code for the case `i=1` _in the for loop embedded in the function_. So the error for `pred(x, 1)` you show above is indeed one example of erronoues behaviour if leaving out the 0 from the cumsum, but it's not the single case affected by it.

Comment: You are correct. I wrote that in haste. It is there to handle the first lag. Was more aiming to show how to test out its importance through sampling and invoking that function. The problem of convergence is for any smaller value of k because lag of first element creates a problem. Will edit the answer.